# Положил на лопатки Linux mint после сноса python3. 7

Tags: python, linux-mint

Добрый день уважаемые люди. После сноса python3. 7 с домашней системы Linux mint начались траблы с оконным менеджером. Стал выдавать ошибку: "либо менеджер окон не поддерживает кнопку расчистки рабочего стола, либо менеджер окон не запущен вовсе" перестал работать терминал. Заголовки у окон перестали отображатся и закрыть их можно только после файл->выход. Alt+Tab не работает. Перемещать не возможно. Кнопка пуска не отображается на панели задач. Видимо что после того как указал ссылку на новую версию питона с 2.7 на 3.7 и его удаления система его никак не может найти снова. Вооот косяк так косяк. Переустановить систему не вариант.
Как удалить ссылку? Или есть другое решение? [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Использовал я команду sudo ln -sf /usr/bin/python3.7 /usr/bin/python2. 7

Comment: Удалите сломанную ссылку как обычный файл и переустановите питон (не помешает оба на всякий случай). На ошибки как на фото, наверно, можно не обращать внимания (apt-get в целом вроде не зависит от питона)

Comment: Из чего выходит что по этой ошибке я не могу произвести ни одну из загрузок через apt-get. А менеджером пакетов я не могу воспользоваться да и вообще графическим интерфейсом.

Comment: Что значит не можете? Команда `sudo apt-get install --force-reinstall=true python2.7-minimal python2.7` тоже пишет ошибку и не хочет ничего переустанавливать?

Comment: Хотя, судя по тексту ошибки, нужно ещё переустановить и `python3.7-minimal python3.7 command-not-found python3-apt`

Comment: Удалось восстановить частичную работу Linux mint. Не смогла установится только python3.7-minimal и python3.7. Ругается на отсутствие модуля apt_pkg и жалуется на чем свет стоит dpkg

Comment: В таком случае попробуйте распаковать содержимое пакета python3-apt в систему вручную, после чего переустановить это всё по-нормальному